# Emacs: relation between keystrokes and keys

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, backspace

I am slightly confused by the difference between keys and key-bindings in emacs after reading the first chapter of "Writing GNU Emacs Extensions" (O'Reilly book).

The chapter starts by noting that in some emacs version the keys backspace and DEL, invoke the help menu instead of deleting. In other words, they invoke what is invoked by C-h.

The chapter then goes on to show how to change this behaviour using Lisp code. This is done by binding the keystroke C-h to the delete command.

This is a bit confusing to me. In my mind DEL, Backspace and C-h are three different keystrokes (the first two consisting of a single key).

Why does remapping C-h effect what DEL and Backspace does?

I would have thought to change what backspace does for example, you would remap backspace to another command, not the keystroke C-h.

Answer (score 4):

Unless remapped by a low-level keybord driver, the effect of the Backspace key is to send the character with numeric code 8, which, in certain operating systems, is exactly the same code generated by pressing Control-h. You can verify this fact by simply writing anything on a unix (or linux) shell and then pressing Backspace and Control-h: both of them have the effect of erasing the previous character, since the character with numeric code 8 is interpreted by the operating system as the control character BS, backspace, used either to erase the last character printed or to overprint it (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)). Analogously, Control-J is equivalent to the RETURN key, etc.
The same Wikipedia page describe DEL as “originally intended to be an ignored character, but now used in some systems to erase a character”.

So, when you assign a command to a keystroke you are actually assigning a command to a character code, and if two or more keys generate the same code, by pressing them you are invoking the same command.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! A follow up question: in some versions of emacs RETURN invokes new line and indent, while C-J invokes new line only. How is it possible to assign two different commands to - as you asserted - essentially the same character code?

Comment: If they generate the same character code I think this is not possible, unless you remap them in some other way at the operating system level.

Comment: Also note that there is a significant difference, in terms of the key codes received by Emacs, between running Emacs in a terminal and running it as a GUI application. GUI Emacs gets the opportunity to distinguish between many key sequences which are indistinguishable in a terminal.

Comment: Yes I think you are both right. My version of emacs runs in the GUI, which I guess is why it behaves differently on C-j and RETURN.

Answer (score 0):

@Renzo answered your question about how these keys are related and how binding one can seem to affect another.  Here is some more information about what's going on in this particular case.

See the Emacs manual, node [DEL Does Not Delete](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html).

There you will see this, following an explanation of the problem/confusion:

> To fix the problem in every Emacs session, put one of the following
>   lines into your initialization file (*note Init File::).  For the first
>   case above, where BACKSPACE deletes forwards instead of backwards, use
>   this line to make BACKSPACE act as DEL:
>
> ```
>  (normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 0)
> ```
>
> For the other two cases, use this line:
>
> ```
>  (normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)
> ```
>
> Another way to fix the problem for every Emacs session is to
>   customize the variable `normal-erase-is-backspace`: the value `t`
>   specifies the mode where BS or BACKSPACE is DEL, and `nil`
>   specifies the other mode.  *Note Easy Customization::.

See also the GNU Emacs [FAQ question about Backspace invoking help](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Backspace-invokes-help.html).  There you will see, in addition to information similar to that above, information about how to remap `DEL` on UNIX - use this:

```
stty erase '^?'
```

---

Wrt `C-j` and `RET` (not mentioned in the question, but mentioned in @Renzo's answer): The default behavior of Emacs changed in most programming modes, in Emacs 24.4.

Starting with that release, `electric--indent-mode` is turned on by default, which means that `RET` inserts a newline character and indents, whereas `C-j` just inserts a newline character.  Prior to that release, these keys had the opposite behaviors.  If you prefer the old behavior then do this, to turn off `electric-indent-mode`:

```
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode)
  (electric-indent-mode -1)) ; Use classic `C-j' and `RET'.
```